# Information regarding I/BufferQueueProducer

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am using image_picker 0.6.7+12 to upload a video and video_player 1.0.0 to display the video in my flutter app.

I get an of infinite loop of below statements

I/BufferQueueProducer(29386): SurfaceTexture-0-29386-3 queueBuffer: slot 14 is dropped, handle=0x7adb367f40
I/BufferQueueProducer(29386): SurfaceTexture-0-29386-3 queueBuffer: slot 13 is dropped, hand

If could someone throw light on it, and do I need to worry about it? and How to stop it?

Comment: did you resolve this question already? I am dealing with the same one